Can anyone tell me what is next to the sun?
I took a 4second shot the light was to bright, even tho I could see the planets alignment on my samsung galaxy ASTRO photography I took these picture on June 2 northeast where I stay. If you can see a white dot to the left alittle under the image you can zoom in and is like a star not sure. 

I think you pointed your phone at the sun and took a picture.  This will overload the chip, and the phone's software will try to compensate.  But this kind of overloading can create all sorts of artifacts, which is what I suspect this is...

Looks like a lens flare (reflections inside the lens).  Happens a lot on bright objects and/or long exposures.

I think the question is referring to the small planet-like dot down and to the left rather than the distortion around the sun itself, which is a lens flare (or something like it).

You should not point your camera to the Sun unless it is very close to the Horizon (sunset or sunrise). Otherwise you risk damaging the sensor by getting a blind spot or worse. Not to mention that your photo will be rubbish.

You can answer this yourself: use Stellarium and set the location and time of day to the same as the photo - you'll then see what was next to sun

Mercury/Venus/aircraft

I assume what you're asking about is the tiny speck of light that's down and to the left of that mass of camera distortions around the sun.
This photo lacks context clues like local time of day and which way is 'up' in the photo that would help identify objects, and I'm not sure how zoomed in this photo is, but that said...
Right now Venus is close to the sun in the sky and brightly lit (it's on the opposite side of the sun from us, so we're seeing the fully lit face, if it's not totally washed out by the sun), so it's entirely possible that's Venus. If there's a weirdly bright object in the sky, it's usually Venus or Jupiter, and Venus is close enough to the sun to match this, so that's my best guess.

Here's a current Horizons plot of the ecliptic latitude & longitude of the Sun & Venus, for a Greenwich observer. https://i.sstatic.net/z67rdD5n.png

It could also be an internal reflection of something else in the cabin https://i.sstatic.net/f1wQYs6t.png or even a Federation starship that ended up in Earth's atmosphere. https://youtu.be/57POF6c1pjc?t=14
